# Sort by custom attribute value

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a module named courses on my site and courses page to list all the courses.

I am using following code to get complete list of courses but I want them sorted by a custom attribute **display_order**

```
$_courses = $this->getCourses();
```

following is the class

```
class Abhi_Courses_Block_Course_List extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $courses = Mage::getResourceModel('abhi_courses/course_collection')
                         ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                         ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
        $courses->setOrder('position', 'asc');
        $this->setCourses($courses);
    }
```

I am doing it right now with loop to maintain array and then sort it but is it possible to get the sorted list with above function or by other method.

Comment: how does the method `getCourses` look like?

Comment: I searched it in all files but unable to find it.

Comment: ok. Do this. put in your template this line `echo get_class($this)`. Then you should see a class name in the page. Post that full class code in your question.

Comment: @Marius that method sounds very much like a getter that's probably why the OP can't find it

Comment: @Marius I update the question with the class code ( constructor )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your module is dealing with collection and your `$courses` variable stores this collection I reckon you can do:

```
$courses->setOrder('display_order','asc');
```

Replace 'asc' by 'desc' if you need to change the order.